# Cache a database

Tags: sql, database, caching

I have a problem to solve and at some point of it. It says this:

> I decided to use a relational database to cache calculated data for the next calls.

What does the **cache** part means? Where is that data sorted? Is it saved in a temporal table? How can I access to that information?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Unanswerable.  There are dozens of ways to do what one would consider 'caching' data, from redis to memcached to files to in-memory cache to temporary tables.  You have not provided nearly enough information to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Cache calculated data" means the results of some resource-consuming calculations are stored in a database for faster future access without re-calculation. The data can be stored in one or several tables, it can be versioned or not, so particular implementation may vary.